# outputting items from a list with a specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that stores Car registration plates along with their speed for a stretch of road. The inputted data is stored in two separate lists. The format for vehicle registration is Two letters, two numbers, 3 Letters (eg/DV61 EUB)

I need to output any cars that do not meet this format (personalised or foreign number plates) but are above the speed limit. I'm finding it difficult to pick items from the list that do not meet the standard vehicle registration format.

I need a section of code that pulls any Car Registrations from the list that are a different format and over the speed limit.

```
def nonstandard ():
    global OverLimit
    global speed
    count = 0
    while count < len(RegPlate):
        speed.append(SensorDist/(int(time[count])))
        OverLimit = "Registration Plate: " + str(RegPlate[count])+ "\n" + "Speed recorded: "+ str(speed[count])
        if RegPlate != []:
            with open ("H:\\Programming Practice\\New controlled assessment\\Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
                text_file.write(OverLimit)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Hints: You can index strings, just like you can with lists, so `RegPlate[count][0]` is the first character, etc. And characters (in fact, all strings) have methods named `isdigit`, `isalpha`, and `isspace`, which you can look up in the help.

Comment: I think you want a simple regular expression here, how about: re.match("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$", "AB29CCCk") and then check whether the re has a match?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the items from the list that match the pattern you provided, you can use `re`  and `filter` :

```
import re

l = ["DV61 EUB","DV61 EUBN"]

print  (list(filter(lambda x: re.match("[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$",x),l)))

['DV61 EUB']
```